# Password Regex with min max count in each piece

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regular expression that can specify min and max count of each piece.

**For example with below conditions:**

```
1] Min 3 uppercase letter.
2] min 2 lowercase letter.
3] Min 2 special character. (#?!@$%^&*-)
4] Min 1 number.
5] Min 8 characters.
6] Max 30 characters.
```

I was wrote below regex, but it's do not work some time:

```
((?=(.*\d){1,})(?=(.*[a-z]){2,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){3,})(?=(.*[#?!@$%^&*-])1)(?=\S+$).{8,30})
```

what was wrong?

**Update:**

in `123!ASDaaa` out put is no match.

Comment: Please do post expected output in your post too.

Comment: please read the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `^` and `$` anchors for both ends otherwise match will start anywhere in subject string. You'd better replace each `.*` pattern to its more restrictive definition.

```
^(?=\D*\d)(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){2})(?=(?:[^A-Z]*[A-Z]){3})(?=(?:[^#?!@$%^&*-]*[#?!@$%^&*-]){2})\S{8,30}$
```

Above regex seems bigger but much optimal.

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/9Oejxu/1)

> what was wrong?

- Not having `^` and `$` anchors
- You have a `1` character somewhere in your regex which I think is a typo.

> in `123!ASDaaa` out put is no match.

That's right since there should be at least two minimum special characters but there is one.

Comment: `\S` is a nice feature. Apparently the op overlooked that req.

Comment: Yesa, OP used it in their regex `(?=\S+$)` and I thought they would need it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this one `^(?=(?:.*?[A-Z]){3})(?=(?:.*?[a-z]){2})(?=(?:.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]){2})(?=.*\d).{8,30}$`

Readable version

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?=                           #  3 uppercase letter
      (?: .*? [A-Z] ){3}
 )
 (?=                           # 2 lowercase letter
      (?: .*? [a-z] ){2}
 )
 (?=                           # 2 special characters
      (?: .*? [#?!@$%^&*-] ){2}
 )
 (?=                           # 1 number
      .* \d     
 )
 .{8,30}                       # 8 to 30 characters
 $                             # EOS
```